# Provisioning profiles handling in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone

I have : adhoc_myApp.mobileprovision, i would like to submit my .ipa with mail to the tester.
I have done like this : Product/ Archive, and i have got the error :

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile
```

1. i think that, i should add my adhoc_myApp.mobileprovision to xcode, but how i can do it in xcode 4 ??
2. And how i can shre the ipa?

thanks for your answers

Comment: Please, review your question and be more precise. How did you configure your target for handling provisioning profiles?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean, i al sorry. can you clear please ??

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the provisioning profile to iTunes, or put it manually in **~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles**